# Multiple file upload in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I want to develop a script/ UI which will allow me to upload multiple files with progress bar to my application.
Issue is: As per requirement I have to use IE8 browser and with IE8 browsers XMLHTTPREQUEST and FORMDATA are not supported.
Is there any workaround to have multiple file upload with progress bar for IE8 browsers>

Thanks in advance,
AK

Comment: Yes, multiple file inputs and an iframe. or, flash, along with some intuitive javascript/server work to get the progress. However, you're probably better off dropping the progress requirement in older browsers and just displaying an indeterminate progress bar instead.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following: http://davidwalsh.name/multiple-file-upload 
and http://www.uploadify.com/demos/ It should work with IE8.

Also you can use jQuery plugin: http://www.webappers.com/2009/03/07/multiple-file-upload-plugin-with-jquery-and-flash/